# How to have scalatest/sbt report labelled cases from TableDrivenPropertyChecks

Tags: scalatest

I am new to scalatest and a bit lost in the gigantic inconsistent mess of features

I am trying to write parameterized tests. It seems that the way to do that is via `TableDrivenPropertyChecks`

I managed to get it working with a test like:

```scala
import org.scalatest.funspec.AnyFunSpec
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks

class MyTest extends AnyFunSpec with TableDrivenPropertyChecks {

  describe("the test") {

    val cases = Table(
      ("label", "a", "b"),
      ("case 2 > 1", 1, 2),
      ("case 4 > 3", 3, 4),
    )

    it("should...") {
      forAll(cases) { (name: String, a: Int, b: Int) =>
        assert(b > a)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's fine, but when I run it under `sbt` I just see:

```
[info] MyTest:
[info] the test
[info] - should...
```

If I inject a bad case into the table I can see the test fail so I know they are all being tested.

What I want is for the test runner to report something for each case in the table.

I have seen examples which look like they would provide this, e.g.: https://blog.knoldus.com/table-driven-testing-in-scala/

```scala
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks

class OrderValidationTableDrivenSpec extends FreeSpec with TableDrivenPropertyChecks with Matchers {

  "Order Validation" - {
    "should validate and return false if" - {
      val orders = Table(
        ("statement"                          , "order")
        , ("price is negative"                , Order(quantity = 10, price = -2))
        , ("quantity is negative"             , Order(quantity = -10, price = 2))
        , ("price and quantity are negative"  , Order(quantity = -10, price = -2))
      )

      forAll(orders) {(statement, invalidOrder) =>
        s"$statement" in {
          OrderValidation.validateOrder(invalidOrder) shouldBe false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I try to do this in my test:

```scala
import org.scalatest.funspec.AnyFunSpec
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks

class MyTest extends AnyFunSpec with TableDrivenPropertyChecks {

  describe("the test") {

    val cases = Table(
      ("label", "a", "b"),
      ("case 2 > 1", 1, 2),
      ("case 3 > 4", 3, 4),
    )

    it("should...") {
      forAll(cases) { (label: String, a: Int, b: Int) =>
        s"$label" in {
          assert(b > a)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...I get the error: `value in is not a member of String` from the `s"$label" in {` part.

How do I get my `TableDrivenPropertyChecks` to report something for each case in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of cool features of ScalaTest is that test is not a method, so you can define tests inside a loop:

```scala
Table(
  ("a", "b"),
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4)
).forEvery({ (a: Int, b: Int) => {
  it(s"should pass if $b is greater then $a") {
    assert(b > a)
  }
}})
```

Or even without using `Table`, just with any collection:

```scala
Seq(
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4)
).foreach {
  case (a: Int, b: Int) =>
    it(s"should pass if $b is greater then $a") {
      assert(b > a)
    }
}
```

This way you will get one test per each iteration of a loop, so all the cases will be executed independently, while in case of a loop in a single test it will fail on first failed assertion and won't check remaining cases.

Comment: that looks like a nice pragmatic approach... if this is possible then why does `TableDrivenPropertyChecks` exist?  and why does the `s"$statement" in` syntax not work for me?

Comment: Table allows you to name parameters, it is easier to read that way, especially if you will have multiple parameters of similar type. Regarding why string interpolation does not work in that last example - it does not look like a valid code. I'm not sure what you were trying to do there, `in` is a keyword of a FlatSpec so maybe you mistook some FlatSpec examples with FunSpec.

Comment: ah I suspected it was something to do with different test styles, FlatSpec vs FunSpec... thanks

Comment: This solution is correct in general, but there are a few caveats to be aware of, at least when using `AnyFunSpec`. I'm using Scala 2.13 and ScalaTest 3.2.15, and I have `describe()` blocks within my spec.  In IntelliJ, I'm accustomed to being able to right-click on an individual `describe()` block to run the `it()` tests within the block.  If you do this, the `it()` tests nested under the Table are *not* discovered.  They are discovered *only* if you run the entire spec.  The results are confusing enough that I'm not comfortable using this pattern in any spec that uses `describe()` blocks.